# How to calculate the determinant for all the submatrix of a matrix?

Tags: matrix

I want to calculate (and see) all the submatrixes determinant for one non-square matrix with dimensions nxm.

I know I can get the determinant of a matrix using Det(matrix), but I would like to know if there is a way to calculate all the submatrixes determinants in a batch instead of going one by one.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Do you want to calculate all submatrices with all possible sizes – i.e. all $1\times1, 2\times2, \dots, \min(m,n)\times \min(m,n)$ – or just all the largest submatrices $\min(m,n)\times \min(m,n)$?

Comment: Are you aware of [Minors](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minors.html)?

Comment: A good starting point would be to include a sample matrix to your post and also include any code that you have tried out so far. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! @Domen I want to calculate the determinant of all the possible submatrixes. Will check on Minors

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, the Minors[matrix] give be me a matrix with all the sub determinants of my original matrix?